Spelling/pronunciation 'sc' vs. 'sh'
Today I came across something I've not seen before in Italian: "s" pronounced like the English "sh" (IPA: /ʃ/).
It was in a version of the bible, I Kings 2, dated 2000.  Looking at others, the spelling (of the first syllable) was the same from 2020 back to 1885.
The name in various English versions is consistently spelled "Shimei" which corresponds (as far as I know) to the Hebrew pronunciation.
In an Italian audio version, it is pronounced (nine times) the way we English speakers would pronounce "Shimei" which I would expect to be spelled "Scimei".  But in 1885 it is "Simi" and in all the others "Simei".
Is "sh" ever used in Italian (other than borrowed words) and how often is "Si" pronounced like shi/sci (IPA: /ʃi/)?

That's definitely not standard Italian pronunciation. No non-borrowed Italian word is pronounced like that. One should ask whoever made that audio version why they pronounced that word that way. Some regional pronunciations have a somewhat /ʃ/-like pronunciation of “s”s, but you'd have noticed that in many other words too.

Both readers sound (to my untrained American ear) like native Italian speakers.  But I have also heard the female a small percentage of the time pronounce "chi" like "ci"

Let's tackle one issue at a time. If your only question is about the fact that some unnamed speaker pronounced a specific proper noun in a irregular way, I'm not even sure this is a question for this website. It might be a peculiarity of that speaker, or they were mimicking some other language pronunciation or some other reason unrelated to Italian language.

As far as I can tell, <s> never represents /ʃ/ in native Italian words. It is impossible to say more without seeing your example, but it is possible that the speaker is aware that the native Hebrew pronunciation of the noun uses some form of /ʃ/ and is trying to use the native pronunciation instead of the "obvious" pronunciation from the spelling.
It is also possible that the version of the text the reader is using writes <š> which is often used in Italian transliterations to represent /ʃ/ in Slavic languages (this comes, of course, from the usage of that letter in Croatian and Czech). This sometimes happen in Bibles, but without knowing the edition it's hard to know.

No, if it used <š>, I wouldn't have written .  But imitating the Hebrew is a real possibility.
